# Gitlab : add quick-actions in commit comments

Tags: git, terminal, gitlab, issue-tracking

I've recently discovered that you can close a Gitlab issue from a commit.
For example : `git commit -m "my commit name Fix #12"` will close the issue #12.

I'm also using quick actions in issues comments : `/spend 1h`.

Is it possible to mix those two functionnalities in something like that : `git commit -m "my commit name Fix #12 /spend 1h"` ?
I'v already tried this command, else it's not the good syntax, else this functionnality doesn't exist.

Comment: As of now tag can be added with commit message quick action. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html#commit-messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/quick_actions.md):

> You can enter these commands while creating a new issue or merge request, and
>   in comments.

and

> Each command should be on a separate line in order to be properly
>   detected and executed.

So it would seem that they can only be used in the body of issues, merge requests, and comments. They also need to be placed on their own line.